flutter: How to solve the problem of not being able to move the panel after executing scrollController.jumpTo(0) on SlidingUpPanel
I am building a screen using SlidingUpPanel in flutter.
I would like to implement a panel that closes when double-tapped when the panel is open.
However, if I double-tap the panel after it is open and then scroll down the widget in the panel, after the panel is closed, it will not open and only the widget in the panel will scroll.
If you double-tap a widget in the panel without scrolling, the panel works correctly.
What should I modify to make it work correctly?
Below is the source code.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'SlidingUpPanelDemo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'SlidingUpPanelDemo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PanelController panelController = PanelController();
  DateTime lastTapTime = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SlidingUpPanel(
        controller: panelController,
        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
        panelBuilder: (ScrollController scrollController) {
          return Listener(
            onPointerDown: (event) {
              final now = DateTime.now();
             
              if (now.difference(lastTapTime) <
                  const Duration(milliseconds: 300)) {
                if (panelController.isPanelOpen) {
                  scrollController.jumpTo(0);
                  panelController.close();
                }
              }
              lastTapTime = now;
            },
            child: GestureDetector(
              onDoubleTap: () {},
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) ...{
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      const Divider(color: Colors.grey),
                    }
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I also added the physics to SingleChildScrollView, but it did not work correctly.
SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: panelController.isPanelClosed ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) ... {
                    Container(
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    const Divider(color: Colors.grey),
                  }
                ],
              ),
            ),

